# Y axis won't start at 0 in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this plot I order the ylim to be 0, but the y axis seems to start at -1 anyway, which is very annoying. I really like the y axis to stat at 0. Solutions?

```
sub1=subset(table.popstat,POPSTAT==1,select=c(1,3))
ggplot(sub1, aes(x=YR,y=Freq)) + ylim(0,15) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  annotate("text",x=3,y=14.9,label="Population status",cex=10)
```

Also, I have 30 plots like this, and there are many different ranges on the y axis. I need a generic code that places the text in the upper left corner of the graph no matter what the ymax is. Doable?

Comment: we have no idea what the data looks like. output of `summary(table.popstat)` or `dput()` of all or part of it wld be helpful

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ggplot automatically extends the axes slightly to make sure there is room for points to plot. You can turn this behaviour off with the expand argument

```
ggplot(sub1, aes(x=YR,y=Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  annotate("text",x=3,y=14.9,label="Population status",cex=10) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 15))
```

Comment: you have missed a parenthesis.

Answer (score -1):

```
p + scale_y_continuous(
  limits =   c(0,max_num),
  expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.05))
)
```

this function ( expansion(mult = c(0,0.05))) may help